# tarBarItem icon got chopped off on Iphone

Tags: iphone, tabs, uitabbaritem

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];          
tabBarController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *searchNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:search] autorelease];
searchNav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

[searchNav.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Search" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_find.png"] tag:0];


SettingsView *settings = [[[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
settings.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings] autorelease];
nav2.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[nav2.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Settings" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_Settings.png"] tag:1];

  tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: searchNav, nav2, nil];
```

The problem I have is that the icon image for the tabbaritem got chopped off. How do I make it fit the whole icon in?

Comment: An image does more than a thousand words...

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to resize your icons to approximately 30x30 size ([official reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)).

You can programmatically resize your UIImage as well, but for this type of fixed image, resizing by hand would be wiser.